# Calling thread with char pointer function and std::string produces different results

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, pointers

I have a function that returns a char pointer called `loop_p` and I call it many times on my `main_thread` like this to pass it to the `py_embed` thread:

```
HANDLE handle;
SENDTOPY *cmd=new SENDTOPY();

char* msg=loop_p(ac);
char *argv[4]={"PythonPlugIn2","bridge","test_callsign",msg};
cmd->argc=4;
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_ARGUMENTS; i++ )
{
    cmd->argv[i] = argv[i];
}

handle=(HANDLE) _beginthread(py_embed,0,(void*)cmd);}
```

where `SENDTOPY` is a struct:

```
typedef struct{
    int argc;
    char *argv[4];
}SENDTOPY;
```

The message it sent to python like this and python receives it well:

```
SENDTOPY *arg=(SENDTOPY*)data;
pArgs2=Py_BuildValue("(s)",arg->argv[4]);
pValue2 = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs2);
```

In order to avoid having memory allocation problems i modified the `loop_p` function to a function that returns a `std::string`. I then call that string in the `main_thread`with some modifications:

```
...

std::string msg_python=loop_p(ac);
const char * msg2=msg_python.data();

char *argv[3]={"PythonPlugIn2","bridge","test_callsign"};
cmd->argc=3;
cmd->msg=msg2;
for(...
 ...
```

and i modify the struct `SENDTOPY`to this:

```
typedef struct{
    int argc;
    char *argv[3];
        const char* msg;
}SENDTOPY;
```

I print it to a textfile in the `main_thread` and the message before and after the modifications are equal. But in the `py_embed`thread the const char is no longer what is was, is just a bunch of gibberish. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:
**loop_p code**

```
std::string CNewDisplay::loop_p(int ac){

std::string res("Number of Aircrafts\nHour of simulation\n\n");

for (...
                    ....
        //Route
        textfile<<fp.GetRoute()<<endl;
        std::string route=fp.GetRoute();
        std::replace(route.begin(),route.end(),' ',',');
        res+=route;
        res.append(",\n");

        res.append("\n\n");


        };

return res;

}
```

Comment: Not sure why you are seeing gibberish (you did not include loop_p code), but you should revise msg_python.data() to msg_python.c_str() to ensure you are getting a null-terminated c-style string.

Comment: I did not include the `loop_p`code because at the end of that function the result is the expected. Tried substituting the `msg_python.data()`for `msg_python.c_str()` and the result is the same

Comment: It's threaded. How are you making sure that the python string you call the function with still has data in it by the time the C function is invoked or vice-versa.

Comment: That's exactly where i think the trouble is. When i do this: `SENDTOPY *cmd=new SENDTOPY();` and then copy `msg2` to `cmd->msg`, am i not allocating correctly?

Comment: You are storing a pointer to data within a temporary (stack-based) string, msg_python. Change std::string msg_python=...; to static std::string msg_python=...; (make it static). You can then safely store a pointer to its underlying data.

Comment: That's not a valid answer because at each run of `loop_p code` the string given is different

Comment: Well, if you use msg2 or cmd->msg after msg_python leaves scope, then you will get gibberish. Simply changing msg_python to static will ensure it lives beyond the local scope, and also ensures cmd->msg remains valid. And you can still reassign msg_python each time you call loop_p()!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that you are storing a pointer to the internal guts of a temporary string object created on the stack. If you make string static, then the string's guts will remain valid throughout program execution, and you can safely store pointer to string guts:

```
static std::string msg_python;       // survives beyond local scope

msg_python=loop_p(ac);               // set string to loop_p return value 
const char *msg2=msg_python.c_str(); // get ptr each time since it could change
```

Also, ensure that you use .c_str() to get your c-style char string pointer so that you are assured the string is null-terminated. Using .data() does not guarantee null termination.

Comment: That's it! Just one thing, when should I delete the pointer `msg2`? I mean, the `main_thread` is finished before than the `py_embed` thread, so if I delete it in the `main_thread`i will get an error

Comment: You should not delete msg2. It simply points to msg_python internals, and msg_python gets destructed upon program completion. No leak.